# JavaFX bidirectional ObjectPropertyBinding not working

Tags: java, javafx, binding, properties, javafx-8

i am using many JavaFX Bindings in my app but i have one single binding that dont want to work. Attached listener at b is not triggered with following code

```
a.chosenFileProperty().bindBidirectional(b.selectedFileProperty());
```

Both sides are declared like this:

```
ObjectProperty<File> chosenFile = new SimpleObjectProperty<File>();
```

I cut off several other bindings that could produce sideeffects. But this single binding does not work.

If i use a workaround to add listerns each other the bidrectional binding works

```
a.chosenFileProperty().addListener((ChangeListener<File>) (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    b.setSelectedFile(newValue);
});
b.selectedFileProperty().addListener((ChangeListener<File>) (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    a.setChosenFile(newValue);
});
```

Does anybody know what could be the problem?
I am using exactly the same binding in another case and that works....

Comment: How can you tell the binding doesn't work?  

The problem may lie in another place - maybe you re-create the properties, or return a property other than the one you test?

Comment: Slightly off topic, but... I think you mean "chosen", not "choosen" ;)

Comment: @sillyfly i added a listener on b, that is not called if i change the value of a

Comment: What types are `a` and `b`? Please include the definition of them, and if it's a class you created please include this as well (at least the parts accessing the property)

Comment: a is a control and b is a viewmodel class. But there is not the problem. I am using default JavaFXGetter/Setter

Comment: @Deton: Are you trying to achieve to make nobody able to help you? People ASKING for more code to be able to HELP YOU because there is nothing wrong in the code you've posted. Why do you sabotage the help? Please post more code :)

Comment: Something doesn't make sense. Your listeners should create an infinite loop on change. Since you say they don't, the only possibility is that either `setChosenFile` doesn't change the property returned by `chosenFileProperty`, or `setSelectedFile` doesn't change the property returned by `selectedFileProperty`.

Comment: @sillyfly that is not necessarliy the case. ChangeListener only fires, if the value actually changes.

Comment: Thanks for your hint @sillyfly There was the problem. The setter was called twice by a drop event

Comment: @OJKrylow - Ah, you are correct!  I hadn't thought of it. But this may still explain why `bindBidirectional` did not work.

Comment: And sorry, but a am not allowed to post parts of the code. Even if i mascade it

Comment: Well, glad to see it resolved :). I suggest @sillyfly writes up a short answer so that Delton can close this